# Escape special characters in string

Tags: json, perl, escaping

I'm trying to escape special characters from a string to be used in JSON

Example:

```
$string = qq~Hello, there are special characters here " \n \t \r \ Test~;

$string =~ s/([\\"'\b\f\n\r\t\u])/\\$1/g;

print $string;
```

Result:

```
Hello, here are special characters \" \
  \ \
   Test
```

I've tried other regular expressions and it doesn't work.

I use UTF8

Comment: $string=~s/(\W)/\\$1/g;

Comment: Added backslash in all characters

Hello\,\ there\ are\ special\ characters\ here\ \"\ \
\ \ \ \
\ \ Test

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to. The JSON serializer will — must — handle this for you.

```perl
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'
   use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( encode_json );
   my $s = qq~Hello, there are special characters here " \n \t \r \ Test~;
   say encode_json([ $s ]);
'
["Hello, there are special characters here \" \n \t \r  Test"]
```

Comment: Well. You do if you're writing a JSON serializer from scratch… but that's the worst kind of wheel reinvention.